# sqlite3 How to update column getting part of value from another column

Tags: sqlite

Hi I had a table like below:

[image]

and I try to take only the value after the equal sign from the Address column and put it in the Temperature column. And in the address column only the value before the equal sign should remain

What I expected:
[image]

When I use
`select substr(Adres, 16, 9- 5) Adres from czujniki  WHERE Temperatura='sypialnia'` 
I have got correct values, but how to put in destination place? - this is first question.
This not work as i expected
`update czujniki set Temperatura=(select substr(Adres, 16, 9- 5) Adres from czujniki  WHERE Temperatura='sypialnia') WHERE Temperatura='sypialnia'`
becouse i got empty field.
Second questio is: How to leave the value in the address column only before the equal sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a subquery:

```
update czujniki set 
    temperatura = substr(adres, 16, 9- 5),
    adres = substr(adres, 1, 14)
where Temperatura='sypialnia'
```